# Google Analytics doesn't work in my vuepress project

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, vuepress

Now I hava a vuepress project,

I am trying to use google analytic to track the flow of it.

But it seems there are some problem between my project and google analytic

I already **follow the Document Guide**(
https://vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/official/plugin-google-analytics.html)

to use `yarn add -D @vuepress/plugin-google-analytics`

rather than `npm install -D @vuepress/plugin-google-analytics`

and **also add the plugin to my config**

```
plugins: [
      'vuepress-plugin-mathjax',
      {
        target: 'svg',
        macros: {
          '*': '\\times',
        },
      },
      'latex',
      '@vuepress/google-analytics',
      {
        'ga': 'UA-157347770-2',
      }            
  ],
```

But it still nothing catch by google analytics.

Is there anyone has the same problem or similiar one before?

Thanks for anyone read

Comment: Please define doesnt work  Have you considered contacting the owner of that plugin directly?

Comment: It seems can not detect when someone browse on my website.
Thanks for advice, I will try to contact the owner of the plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration of plugin is wrong.

You have two options to declare the plugin: Babel Style or Object Style.

Babel style:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    ['@vuepress/plugin-google-analytics', { ga: 'XX-000000000-0' }],
  ],
};
```

Object style:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    '@vuepress/plugin-google-analytics': {
      ga: 'XX-000000000-0',
    },
  },
};
```

For more details, please see the documentation: https://vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/using-a-plugin.html#babel-style

Comment: Babel Style works!  Object style will cause wrong message ( the `:` after `@vuepress/plugin-google-analytics` can't be accepted)

Thank you,this  helps a lot.